# Writing a log file with tee

Tags: unix, echo, ksh, tee

There is my problem,
I work with `ksh` script and i try to make a log file with function `tee` and with :

- informations that will be shown on screen
- informations that will not be shown on screen.

So i used `tee` to handle all `echo` in my script and i wanted to redirect output from specific echo to go **only** in log file.

```
foo(){
        echo Hello               # screen + log file
        echo World >> "tee.txt"  # only log file
        echo !                   # screen + log file      
}             
rm -f "tee.txt"
foo | tee -a "tee.txt"
```

### Screen **output**

```
Hello
!
```

That's okay.

### Log file

But in **log file** :

```
World
Hello
!
```

`echo` redirection writed **before** `tee`.

### Conclusion

So, does there is something that is like echo who will only store output and not showing it to screen ? 
To get that output in log file with tee ?

```
Hello
World
!
```

Comment: This question is quite confusing - it's about `ksh` and a very weird use case I can't understand. For some reason this showed up when I google `tee` and `log file` but that's really not at all what I wanted as a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It worked for me on ksh.

```
rm -f "tee.txt"

foo()
{
    echo Hello
    stty -echo
    echo World >> "tee.txt"
    stty echo
    echo !
}
foo | tee -a "tee.txt"
```